# how to integrate jenkins with react jest testing results

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, jestjs

My project is using reatJS, jest is used to do unit test and also to generate the coverage report.
Now I need to use jenkins to automatically build the project and then display the code coverate result. But I could not find out jest plugins in jenkins.
Can anyone show me how you integrate jest with jenkins for displaying coverage?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If cannot get a direct plugin use html publish plugin and point it to your test reports index.html or whatever equivalent to it.
I have got a custom inhouse made oracle db code quality tool which produces html result and using html publish plugin brings up a link in the lefthand side of the job which shows the job.
You may use emailext plugin to send the result aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the above answer, in my case I'm using a declarative pipeline, and in the final stage after we run the tests in the pipelines we added.

The folder where the results are generated is `coverage/lcov-report`, and we need to point to the `index.html` generated.

i.e.

```
publishHTML(target: [
            allowMissing: true,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
            keepAll: true,
            reportDir: 'coverage/lcov-report',
            reportFiles: 'index.html',
            reportName: 'Jest Test Reports',
            reportTitles: 'Jest Test Reports'])
```

more documentation here:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher/